# eigendecomposition of symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

for any symmetric real matrix $S$, the following eigendecomposition exists:

$$ S = Q \Lambda Q^{\top} $$

where $Q$ is a unitary matrix, consisting of the eigenvectors of $S$ [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Symmetric_matrices) . 
By definition of unitary, we have  $Q^{\top}Q=QQ^{\top}=I$.
Given an orthonormal set of eigenvectors, $Q^{\top}Q=I$, is trivial. How can one show $QQ^{\top}=I$ ?

Comment: If $Q^TQ = I$, then $Q^T = Q^{-1}$. Now $QQ^{-1} = I$, so...

Comment: it is a full rank matrix and its inverse is $Q$. I don't get your question.

Comment: You might find [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i) useful; it explains why $AB=I$ implies $BA=I$ for general square matrices $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thanks All. it simply answered my question. I was not thinking about it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathbf Q^\top\mathbf Q=\mathbf I$, then $\mathbf Q\mathbf Q^\top\mathbf Q=\mathbf Q$. Then consider postmultiplying both sides by $\mathbf Q^{-1}$...

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I think, the more interesting part in the original question is in the direction: "why is it with a symmetric matrix **S**, that the diagonalization $ \small S = Q  \Lambda  Q^{-1} $ provides a *unitary* matrix **Q** , such that $ \small Q^T = Q^{-1} $ ?" Which, of course, can be answered by considering the equality of **S** with its transpose: $\small S = S^T=(Q^T)^{-1} \Lambda Q^T = Q \Lambda Q^{-1} \to Q=(Q^T)^{-1} $ and $ \small Q^{-1}=Q^T $